# Show/hide div class based on the variable in the controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, razor

I have a string in the controller which queries Rest API stores the response

```
string rmID = searchLogic.GetRoomID(rmName.Substring(0, rmName.IndexOf(' '))).Result;
```

This field is not in the Model class. I need to check if the `string rmID is Empty or Null` in the Index.cshtml and show/hide a div class

```
@{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(rmID))
    {
        <div class="row" style="padding-bottom:2rem">

            <div class="col-md-9" style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;text-align:center">
                <b>
                    **You have selected not valid room**
                </b>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
}
```

But the above one doesnot work

Comment: `rmID` needs to be passed to the view. Where does it exist in the controller?

Comment: @Jasen `string rmID = searchLogic.GetRoomID(rmName.Substring(0, rmName.IndexOf(' '))).Result;` is within the Controller of the view

Comment: @user4912134, how do you pass the value of `rmID` from controller to the VIew?

Comment: @XinranShen I am not sure how to pass that from the controller to  the view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ViewBag` to pass the value of `rmID` from controller to the View.

```
string rmID = searchLogic.GetRoomID(rmName.Substring(0, rmName.IndexOf(' '))).Result;

ViewBag.Id = rmID;
```

Then in the view, Use `@ViewBag.Id` to receive the value and do judgement.

**View**

```
@if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(@ViewBag.Id))
    {
        <div class="row" style="padding-bottom:2rem">

            <div class="col-md-9" style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;text-align:center">
                <b>
                    **You have selected not valid room**
                </b>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
```